# Issues in Visual Studio 2015 after upgrading from PostSharp 4.1.15 to 4.3.18

Tags: visual-studio-2015, postsharp

After upgrading from PostSharp 4.1.15 to 4.3.18 in we experience the following issues in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3) the following issues:

1. Building PostSharp projects has become extremely slow.
2. Breakpoint in the code of some of the projects, for which PostSharp is enabled, are not hit.

When changing the PostSharp setting ‘Disable PostSharp for this configuration’ on the projects property page from ‘no’ to ‘yes’ the issues above are resolved, but no PostSharp code is generated.

Downgrading to 4.2.29 solves issue 1, but doesn’t solve issue 2 and causes another issue: Typescript debugging in VS is not working anymore. When a breakpoint in Typescript is hit, Visual Studio crashes.

Downgrading to 4.1.15 solves issue 1, but doesn't solve issue 2.
TypeScript debugging is working.
It isn't possible to change the PostSharp Features options anymore. On the Features tab it says: These sesttings can’t be modified with the current license.

Comment: Regarding #1 - this is most probably due to PostSharp checking the source repository for changes when you don't have a commercial license. As of version 4.3 PostSharp allows you to build without license if you don't modify the source (http://doc.postsharp.net/licensing-shared-source-code). The issue affects TFS repositories.To confirm, please review the diagnostic log output from MSBuild. Look for the following `: verbose PS0035: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\\..\IDE\tf.exe status.`

Comment: Regarding #2 - PostSharp 4.3 implements some debugger extensions to improve the debugging experience. It may cause some compatibility issue in your case. First of all, make sure that both PostSharp NuGet package and VS extension are version 4.3. Would it be also possible for you to provide a sample that reproduces the issue with breakpoints not hit?